# Отрицательные местоимения

Tags: местоимения

Подскажите, пожалуйста. Почему отрицательные местоимения образуются ТОЛЬКО от вопросительных? А например, от указательных местоимении нельзя образовать отрицательные. Например, указательное местоимение ТОТ. Если мы хотим сделать отрицание, то будет - НЕ ТОТ (отрицательная частица НЕ с указательным местоимением ТОТ). Так почему нету ОТРИЦАТЕЛЬНОГО местоимения "нитот", например?

Comment: Забавный вопрос, никогда об этом не задумывался)

Comment: хотя есть слова "нет", "нету", "нечто", "ништо". В немецком есть нихт типа ни-я, в английском есть neither ~ not the other

Comment: @Буратино  Хотя вы правы)  Я тоже так думаю Хорошо бы увидеть ваш ответ.

Comment: Этот вопрос вы задавали на разных ресурсах, и вам уже ответили .Что вас не устроило?

Comment: Кочующий вопрос  https://school.infourok.ru/vopros-otvet/f3530e5e-e10f-464f-8ccc-11b55f307bca

Comment: Серж, давайте предположим, что Павла не удовлетворил ответ (полученный с другого ресурса): «отрицательные формы местоимений образуются только от вопросительных, потому что это языковая особенность и логически связано с способом выражения отрицания и обращения к определенному лицу или предмету». На самом деле, ему интересно знать: что послужило причиной возникновения этой самой «языковой особенности»?

Answer (score 1):

Как утверждает википедия, с XVII века при записи речи стало принято оставлять «пробелы» между словами. Смыл текста, записанного с такой разметкой, воспринимается проще. Скорость чтения повышается. Такой стиль записи послужил усложнению правил правописания.
«Вопросы слитного / раздельного написания сочетаний полных слов со служебными элементами (предлогами, частицами и т. п.) представляет собой сложную для учащихся часть орфографии русского (и не только) языка.
https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9F%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B1%D0%B5%D0%BB
Слово - это единица языка, служащая для наименования понятий, лиц, действий, состояний,признаков, связей, отношений, оценок (определение из Словаря С. И. Ожегова).
Слово часто определяется как группа (сочетание) звуков, объединяющихся одним (общим) ударением». Дифференциацию слов в потоке речи называют «синтаксической функцией ударения».

В потоке (современной русской) речи вопросительные местоимения «охотно сливаются» с частицами НЕ и НИ под общим ударением: нЕкому, нЕкого, нЕчего и никтО, ничЕй, никакОй. Правила орфографии требуют слитного (без пробела) написания таких слов, отражая специфику их произношения.
Образовавшиеся в результате такого «слияния» слова получили наименование «отрицательные местоимения» Частицы НЕ и НИ в составе этих слов выполняют роль приставок.

Иначе обстоит дело с указательными местоимениями. Выговаривая сочетание частиц НЕ / НИ с указательными местоимениями легко заметить, что оба слова сохраняют собственное ударение: нИ тОт, нИ Этот, нЕ тЕ, нЕ такИе. Это значит, что и местоимение, и частица продолжают оставаться самостоятельными словами (т.е., не происходит их «слияния» в одно слово, под одним ударением).   Данная особенность произношения закреплена правилами письма, согласно которым между частицей НЕ / НИ и указательным местоимением должен оставаться «пробел».
В итоге получается, что особенность произношения и является обстоятельством, мешающим «образованию» отрицательных местоимений от местоимений указательных.

Вспомним, когда частицы НЕ и НИ становятся приставками:
http://intelligentplus.ru/index.php?area=1&p=static&page=t31

Comment: Мне кажется, что дело не в пробелах,  а в существовании таких местоимений. Нет слова — нет слитного написания. А вот почему его нет — это надо доказывать.

Comment: @Sharon, согласен с вами. Дело в пробелах и ударении, а в значении самих слов.

Comment: @Серж Спасибо за поддержку.  Интересно, как  в английском языке:  The wrong one  —  не тот,  Not this one — не этот,  someone  — некто,  nobody — никто, но: There is no — никакой.

Comment: Значит, дело не только в особенностях русского языка, как считается. Это проблема общего языкознания.

Answer (score 1):

1. **Диалог:**

   ```
   — Тебе какой рассказ у этого писателя больше 
   нравится, ТОТ или ЭТОТ?

   — НИКАКОЙ мне не нравится, ни тот, ни этот. Мне у 
   него вообще НИЧЕГО не нравится.
   ```
2. Речь идет **о двух рассказах автора** и о его творчестве в целом. Это вроде бы предметы: на них можно указать (тот и этот), но указательные местоимения **не имеют конкретного** значения, оно временное и **УСЛОВНОЕ** даже в заданной ситуации. Поэтому в словаре нет слов ***нитот, ниэтот***.
3. А вот  местоимения ***ничего, никакой*** вполне конкретны. Они говорят о том, что **нет предмета или признака**, который удовлетворял бы требованиям, **ни один не подходит**. И в словаре есть **значения** таких слов.
4. Как представить такой предмет или признак? Образно говоря, в виде **ПУСТОГО ПРОСТРАНСТВА,** ничем не заполненного.
5. Другими словами, значение местоименных существительных ***никто*** и ***ничто***  — в отсутствии нужного по смыслу предмета.

**В английском языке:** The wrong one — не тот, Not this one — не этот, ***someone*** — некто (неопред. местоимение), ***nobody*** — никто (отрицат. местоимение), но: There is no — никакой.

Значит, дело не только в особенностях русского языка, как иногда считается. Это проблема **общего языкознания**.

**Из других ответов в Сети:** "*Таким образом, **в русском языке** отрицательные формы местоимений образуются только от вопросительных, потому что это языковая особенность и логически связано с способом выражения отрицания и обращения к **определенному лицу или предмету*".**

**ИЗ СЛОВАРЕЙ:**

**ТОТ**, того; м.;  I. местоим. прил. 2. Указывает на какой-л. предмет, лицо, **выделяемые из ряда других**. Вошёл не в этот подъезд, а в тот. Купи вон тот плащ! Взгляни на тот рисунок.

**НИЧТО** [шт], ничего, ничему, ничем, ни о чём (в сочет. с предлогами пишется раздельно: ни за что, ни для чего, ни у чего, ни с чем, ни при чём и т.п.); **местоим. сущ**. (в отриц. предл.). **Ни один, никакой предмет, ни одно, никакое явление, дело и т.п.** Ни о чём не думать. Ничего не видно. Ничем не отличаться. Я не могу ничего делать. Их н. не волнует. Ничему не удивляйся. В магазинах ничего нет.

**НИКАКОЙ,** -ая, -ое; (в сочет. с предлогами пишется раздельно: ни у какого, ни к какому, ни с каким, ни о каком и т.п.). **местоим. прил.** 1. (с последующим отрицанием). Выражает полное отрицание; **ни один (из всех, многих, возможных)**. Никаких продуктов не купил. Н. врач не поможет. Н. рыбы в озере теперь нет.

Comment: Sharon, в Вашем сообщении легко запутаться. В нем идут отсылки и к «проблеме общего языкознания», и к «языковой особенности (в русском)». Не затруднит ли Вас дополнить свое сообщение (или выделить его в существующем) ответом на вопрос школьника: «почему нету ОТРИЦАТЕЛЬНОГО местоимения "нитот"»? Иначе говоря, чем можно объяснить такую особенность русского языка?

Answer (score 1):

```
 Не затруднит ли Вас дополнить свое сообщение (или выделить 
 его в существующем) ответом на вопрос школьника: «почему 
 нету ОТРИЦАТЕЛЬНОГО местоимения "нитот"? Иначе говоря, чем 
 можно объяснить такую особенность русского языка? (Из 
 комментария.)
```

Ответ **на комментарий** и еще один ответ для школьника

Попутно изучаем **английский язык** (для сравнения)

```
       ничто    Nothing
       нечто    Something
       никто    nobody
       некто    someone
       ни этот  Neither one
       ни тот   Neither one
       не тот  The wrong one
       не этот  Not this one
```

1. Это особенность **не только** русского языка,  но и особенность, к примеру,  **английского языка**  тоже.

Можно видеть, что в этих языках  отрицательные и неопределенные местоимения образуются от **ВОПРОСИТЕЛЬНЫХ** местоимений и пишутся **в одно слово**,  а **УКАЗАТЕЛЬНЫЕ** местоимения таких слов **не образуют**, а пишутся с НЕ и НИ раздельно   — **в два слова**, как словосочетания.

2. Что же обозначает отрицательные местоимения ***никто/ничто***? Значение у них такое:  **ни один, никакой предмет, никакое лицо и** т.п. из тех, что были **названы**.  Вполне **конкретное** и нужное значение.
3. Конечно, можно пойти **дальше** и  дать название и таким словам тоже: ***не тот, не этот, ни тот, ни этот***  для предметов и лиц, на которые было **указано** (то есть писать их слитно).  Но  такие  слова (а их четыре!)   мало о чем говорят: в любой момент говорящий может  **изменить** свое указание и ***тот*** предмет назвать ***этим*** предметом. Так что эти слова  оказались **невостребованными**  ни в русском, ни в английском языке.

Comment: Sharon, спасибо (от меня) за дополнение к Вашему первому сообщению! 
Заметим все же, что «неделимое» в русском, - в английском иногда «распадается на составляющие»: никого = no one, нисколько = not at all, ничуть = not at all, никакой = there is no,  нЕкого = no one, некому (вернуть долг) = there is no one (to repay the debt), а бывает и наоборот: разговор ни о чем = talking about nothing.

Думается, что объяснять правила правописания словосочетаний с местоимениями в русском языке через английский вряд ли уместно.

Comment: Не могу не возразить по поводу «невостребованности». Указательные местоимения  «в комплекте» с частицами отрицания НЕ и НИ очень даже востребованы в русском языке (и во многих других тоже). Невостребованным же (а точнее - под запретом) оказалось их слитное написание. Попытки объяснить причину (резон, мотив, повод) для возникновения этого запрета в Ваших ответах мне обнаружить так и не удалось...

Comment: Попробуйте обнаружить еще где-нибудь) Слитно пишутся слова, которые есть в языке. В словаре для них можно найти статью, где указано их значение. Слов нитот, ниэтот там нет. // Кстати, как вы объясните, что в английском языке тоже нет таких слов? Ну просто все в точности как у нас.